# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException Using Double

Tags: java, compiler-errors, double, runtime-error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class palomba2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //allows input to be read
        // VOLUME OF A PRISM

        int prLngth, prWdth, prHght, prVol;

        System.out.print("Enter the length of the prism in feet: ");
        prLngth = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the width of the prism in feet: ");
        prWdth = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the height of the prism in feet: ");
        prHght = keyboard.nextInt();

        prVol = prLngth * prWdth * prHght;

        System.out.print("The volume of the prism is " + prVol);
        System.out.print(" feet.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        // AREA/CIRCUMFERENCE OF A CIRCLE

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

        double radius, circ, area;

        System.out.print("Enter the radius of a circle rounded to the nearest hundreth: ");
        radius = keyboard.nextInt();

        circ = 2 * radius * 3.14159265358979;
        area = radius * radius * 3.14159265358979;

        System.out.print("The circumference of the circle is " + format.format(circ));
        System.out.print("units.");
        System.out.print("The area of the circle is " + format.format(area));
        System.out.print("units.");
    }
}
```

Everything in my code works up until I input the radius of the circle. It comes up with the error messages after I input a radius.

```
 Enter the radius of a circle rounded to the nearest hundreth: 2.12

 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:860)
     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
     at palomba2.main(palomba2.java:52)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Do you know what a `java.util.InputMismatchException` is? If not it is time to read on it :-)

Answer (score 3):

You type a double variable `2.12` but trying to read it as an `int` : input mismatch -> `InputMismatchException`

---

Also, the variable `radius` is of type `double` so you cannot give to it an `int` value (also you, you need :

- `radius = keyboard.nextDouble();`

---

But still better to use `radius = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine())` to consume the return char (same for `int` : `int val = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine())`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the:

`radius = keyboard.nextInt();`

to:

`radius = keyboard.nextDouble();`

because the variable `radius` is declared as `double`
it should look like this:

```
double radius, circ, area;
System.out.print("Enter the radius of a circle rounded to the nearest hundreth: ");
radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I noticed it after reading through my code a million times. Silly me. It's my second day coding, so I'm probably going to miss these simple things a lot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "*because the variable radius is declare as double*" not quite, it is because user provides `double` but code is designed to read `int` via `nextInt()` so it can't handle `.12` part.